# Typescript enum switch does not go into any case

Tags: typescript, enums, switch-statement

I am trying to use switch with ENUM and it doesn't seem to work

```
function ConvertToTableName(targetName: PostType): string {
  let tableName = ""
  switch (targetName) {
    case PostType.COMMUNITY:
      tableName = '"COMMUNITY_POST_COMMENT"'
      break
    case PostType.RECOMMEND:
      tableName = '"RECOMMEND_POST_COMMENT"'
      break
  }
  console.log(targetName)
  console.log(tableName)
  return tableName
}
```

Here's my function.

```
console.log(targetName) //PRINTS RECOMMEND
console.log(tableName) //PRINTS NOTHING
```

even though targetName is PostType type and has value RECOMMEND,
targetName doesn't go into any of the cases thus tableName is not set to anything.

here's my enum:

```
export enum PostType {
  RECOMMEND,
  COMMUNITY
}
```

enum and the function are placed in different files but properly imported

How can I fix so that switch clause work as expected?

Comment: but it works on my machine :P http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBACg9gZwC4BUCeAHYUDeAoKKAJQFEBhAeQFkqSA5AEQBoCpKaBVOgSRQE08AXzx4AZmBABjJAEs4INvIBuwAE6o4KAIYAjADbA6WiMAAUSLaoDmwJEZMAuWIlSZgASifJVMkFdysBkhQFvqGxtgAvFAARDEA3KwIAO4ySJIAFlDmljZ2Ee4BhISSWgjY8MjoWAB07FRcvHwOrMUhugb2UVAA5DH1jfwA+jAUAMooQ-X0KDE9iW2EOqrAWgDWC8Wl5c5VbjWk04wti+1hXVDRfYfUtIwj45NHs-OtxcurG6zCJfIIcAYano4FYctZbF13JtJH8AcAgSCcucCpsVkgwKoFKFOhFEsI8GRlGoNNpkSZTJVXLUBjx+FCgA

Comment: Also, `console.log(targetName)` should be printing 1 or 0. To print the enum name you would use: `console.log(PostType[targetName]);`

Comment: my argument `targetName` comes from GraphQL's query's enum and I guess that has to do with the reason why switch doesn't work + `console.log(targetName)` prints `RECOMMEND` instead of 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

My problem was GraphQL's ENUM type sending ENUM as literal instead of number